# Excessive SWF size for a simple external CSS sheet

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

I'm working on a flex app which is built in Apache 4.12 and I am loading an external CSS file to change some theme related stuff. I have the sheet set to "Compile CSS to SWF"

This all works fine but the SWF file size of this single sheet is more than 3 Meg and it only contains about 5 simple style declarations, and I have 2 namespaces declared in it...Not sure if that matters.

How can I get this SWF smaller so it can load up a little faster plus not add such a large addition to my package size?

It seems like it could be a bug or something dopey I'm doing??

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Marco

Comment: Decompile that SWF and see what's taking the space. I have a hunch it's just dragging a bunch of SWCs with text formatting and maybe even embedded fonts.

Comment: Thanks Creative Magic. I'll give that a shot. I've never decompiled an SWF before, but I'm sure it can't be that hard..

Comment: Adding the `-size-report=mysizereport.xml` flag to mxmlc's arguments will output an XML file indicating the assets included in your SWF and their sizes which will be useful for this.

Comment: Thanks Nicko. Yep I did this and I could see a great deal of stuff was being included with the SWF...I just don't know how to control what is added to the compiled CSS SWF file so I can minimise it?? I'm fairly newbish so I don't actually know what it needs or how to manually compile a css. It's obviously bloated though. I tried compiling the CSS from the command prompt and found it got a great deal smaller...However it reported some namespace errors and such and only some styles were working when I loaded it. Thanks, Marco

Comment: You can also use swfdump to see what's in it - that included in the SDK.

Comment: Most common issue is fonts and character ranges - you can restrict the character range included. Instructions here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e04.html

Comment: Thanks Justin.I'll take a look into this more. Good work on the new Flex 4.12 version by the way! Cheers